# Using OpenGL 3.0+ in Windows with SDL

Tags: windows, opengl, sdl, glfw, glew

In OS X to get OpenGL 3.0+ with SDL2 I need to do the following: include `SDL2/sdl.h`, `OpenGL/gl3.h` and specify `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION` and `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION` in `SDL_SetAttribute()`.

I would like this to be portable on Windows, but I've heard that Microsoft implements only OpenGL 1.1: so linking against `opengl32.dll` and including `gl/gl.h` won't give me access to 3.0+ functions.

Do I have to download additional headers (like `gl3.h` I use OS X), include them and request a 3.0+ context via SDL?

Comment: You have `glew` in your question tags; it actually _is_ an answer. Just include `glew.h` before anything else, call `glewInit` and you're good to go (or any other loader, or `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` directly).

Comment: @keltar so does this mean that I have to have `glew` library to get the latest `OpenGL` version on Windows? Is there a way to archive this only with SDL?

Comment: @ibe: You don't have to use GLEW specifically. You can use any [OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library). You can even [manually write such code](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions), but there's really no point in doing that. I really don't understand why it is that some people have such problems with using libraries. They exist to help you get your stuff done. Not using an OpenGL loader is like using the palm of your hand to drive a nail instead of the hammer that's sitting 4 feet away.

Comment: Yes you have to load functions during run time. SDL only provides you with universal `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` (which is `wglGetProcAddress` *or* dlsym/GetProcAddress on windows, `glXGetProcAddress` on X11, etc.). `opengl32` isn't a driver itself but microsoft's shim, as opposed to unix systems, where `libGL` is actual display dirver's library. But then again, if you use functions directly, it may fail to link on machine without needed functions in driver (e.g. headless virtual machine with buildbot for automated builds).

Comment: thanks. i've decided to use `glew` headers for OpenGL instead of platform-specific like `gl3.h` on OS X.